# Flex Webservice in swf question

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, flash, release, deployment

I'm trying to use  for getting infomation from an WSDL file online. I have no problem running and testing in my FLEX 3 builder. However, After I export release build into SWF file. The program doesn't work even running local. IE/firefox said "transferring data from http://www.webservicex.net" on the status bar and doesn't response.

This is my code for webService tag:

```
<mx:WebService id="stockWebService"
    wsdl="http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL"
    fault="handleFault(event)" result="handleResult(event)"/>
```

I try to google the problems but cannot found the answer. Can someone please help me? Thank you very much for you time!

Comment: Looks like you forgot to put in your webservice tag.
But, maybe try creating a textarea, and outputting the result to it from both the fault handler and the result handler. That why you can start by seeing

Comment: It was a formatting issue.  I fixed it.

Comment: Did you try running it through the debugger? Any errors or (uncatched) responses?